# Como obtener el control dropdownlist de un gridview cuando doy clic en boton realizar accion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, webforms

**Como obtener el control dropdownlist de un gridview cuando doy clic en boton realizar accion**

Estoy tratando de obtener el control dropdownlist cuando doy click al boton realizar accion de la fila correspondiente pero siempre me trae null porque no lo encuentra cabe mencionar que los listItems del dropdownlist son diferentes dependiendo del registro a evaluar

[image: this is what I want]

**Code behing**

`protected void gvLista_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

string varId = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id"));
var ctrlDDlActions = e.Row.Cells1.FindControl("ddlActions") as DropDownList;
ctrlDDlActions.ID = ctrlDDlActions.ID + "" + varId.Replace("-", "");
}
}`

```
protected void BtnDoAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
var id = Guid.Parse(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);

var varId = id.ToString().Replace("-", "_");

            var control = "ddlActions_" + varId;
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();    
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gvLista.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {                       
                        ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl(control);   //<-- no encuentra el control                         
                }
            }

var selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue; //<--- ddl siempre viene null 
}
```